# OpenCV Error: Bad number of channels (Source image must have 1, 3 or 4 channels)

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am using opencv to find the contours, and show each contour on the image frame,  I had seen the example using converting contour into rectangle like

```
`boundingRect( Mat(contours_poly[i]) );`
```

so I think it might be ok to work  **cv::imshow("parking2", Mat(contours[i]));**

```
cv::findContours(img_resized,contours,CV_RETR_LIST,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
cout<<"contour size   "<<contours.size()<<endl;
for(int i = 0;i <contours.size();i++){
  cv::imshow("parking2", Mat(contours[i]));
}
```

But ultimately, it doesn't work , giving me the error - OpenCV Error: Bad number of channels (Source image must have 1, 3 or 4 channels)

Note: the original image is a grey image not RGB image.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for being lazy / unclear the other day, but even if you put your contours-pointlist into a Mat, that does not make it an image.  it should probably be:

```
Rect br = boundingRect( contours_poly[i] ); // the rect containing all points of the contour

Mat cropped(img_resized, br);               // the cropped part of the original image 

imshow( "parking2", cropped );              // show cropped part only
```

also, if you repeatedly call imshow with the same windowname in a loop, you'll only see the *last* image, as one call will overwrite the other